# Multiple wordpress logins not working on local host

Tags: wordpress

I am building 3 different wordpress websites on localhost (xampp) in 3 separate directories.
I used the same username and password for all 3 and immediately after installation i could log in to each.
After having made no changes, 2 of 3 are telling me the password is incorrect.
Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Google to the rescue!
I found the answer here.

https://www.coderchamp.com/blogs/coder-champ/wordpress-multisite-login-not-working